# Keep GNU/Linux Desktop System on while downloading

Tags: firefox, suspend

how to keep the GNU/Linux Desktop System on --( ignoring suspend session from Desktop Environment setting ie. KDE )-- while download in progres in firefox, uget or etc?

- is there any add-on for firefox or Uget?
- or any advanced setting?

thanks.